# How to turn on a laptop without the case

Tags: hacking

We are trying to use a laptop motherboard in an automotive project for running an AI and, in the end of reducing size, we want the laptop without the case. The laptop is an HP Omen 15 from last year (similar to HP Omen 15-en1011ns, in case you need it). The problem is that this laptop has the power-on button on the keyboard so we need to locate the power button signal on the motherboard. However, it's very difficult to locate the power button track in the flexible cable that connects to the motherboard so we can't measure continuity. How would you proceed?
My guess is that if we knew how the power-on circuit works, we could locate it in the pcb, but I haven't been able to find it on the internet. How do laptops usually do it?

Comment: Desktop PC:s have this Restore function in Bios, if there's a power loss, what to do when power returns. One alternative is Power on, then it will always power on when power is restored. If this is the case with your laptop I don't know, but it's cheap for you to check.

Comment: Most systems provide a kind of wakeup from USB keyboard. You could program a pseudo keyboard using an AtTiny85 or similar and send such a code. And there is the WakeOnLAN feature. Both options do not require to dive deep into the board hardware.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the power button could be integrated into the keyboard matrix row/column and thus when pressed result in the keyboard controller sending a scan code that the BIOS detects and turns on.

Alternatively there could be a pair of dedicated wires that are shorted when the power button is pressed.

In either case, the easiest way to get the system to boot, is to use the keyboard interface in exactly the way it was designed - by having something that interfaces with the ribbon connector, which momentarily shorts the same two wires that the power button does.

---

In either case, you will need to find which two wires you need to short on the keyboard header. This is pretty much a case of testing all combinations on the keyboard ribbon cable until you find the one that works.

With the keyboard disconnected, I'd start by using something to press and hold the power button - perhaps using a ball bearing and some tape to hold it down. Make sure it is the only button pressed. Then you are free to start trying to find which to pins are shorted. There should only be two. Your keyboard might have diodes so polarity could matter, and if there is a backlight its power pins could cause some confusion.

Be systematic about it. Using a multimeter in continuity mode:

1. Place one probe on the first pin, then wipe the other probe across *all* of the other pins to see if you get a beep.

   - If no beep, move the first probe onto the next pin, then repeat step 1.
   - If beep, keep track of the rough location you found it, and move to step 2.
   - If no beep and all pins tested with the first probe, swap probes and start again (could be diodes in the matrix).
2. Once you get a beep, you now know one of the two pins used by the power button. Keeping the first probe in place, slowly touch the second probe on each of the other pins nearby where you heard the beep in step 1. This should allow you to narrow down and test just a few other pins to find the exact one which provides continuity.

It shouldn't take long to find the first pin - even with say 25 pins, you can do it in a few minutes as the wiping process doesn't require precision. Once you have found the pair of pins, you are good to go. There should be precisely one combination of row and column (or dedicated pin pair) that represents the power button.

Comment: Good idea. We will try next week and see if it works